# How to fetch only selected date's data from a website using VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel, date, web, web-crawler

I have crawled a website (mentioned in the code), using VAB, and stored the data in an excel file. My user form has an option button to "select today's data". Accordingly, I am trying to modify the following code for the same. Will you please help me? I tried several options but unable to achieve what I want.

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub Extract_TD_text()

Dim URL As String
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim TRelements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TRelement As HTMLTableCell

Dim r As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim offSet As Integer
Dim maxOffSet As Integer
Dim currentDate As Date

URL = "https://www.gebiz.gov.sg/scripts/main.do?sourceLocation=openarea&select=tenderId"
Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
offSet = 0
r = 0
k = 0

If UserForm1.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
cuerrentDate = Date

With IE
    .navigate URL
    .Visible = True
     'Wait for page to load
    While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
    Set InputElements = .document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each InputElement In InputElements
        If InputElement.getAttribute("name") = "strBtnLast" Then
            maxOffSet = CInt(Split(Split(InputElement.getAttribute("onclick"), "Navigator(")(1), ")")(0))
        End If
    Next
    While offSet <= maxOffSet
        offSet = offSet + 10
        Set TRelements = .document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each TRelement In TRelements
         'Look for required TD elements - this check is specific to VBA Express forum - modify as required
            If TRelement.className = "row_even" Or TRelement.className = "row_odd" Or TRelement.className = "header_subone" Then
                i = 0
                For Each Child In TRelement.ChildNodes
                    Sheet1.Range("A1").offSet(r, i).Value = Child.innerText
                    i = i + 1
                Next
                r = r + 1
            End If
        Next
        If offSet <= 10 Then
            Sheet1.Rows(1).Delete
            Sheet1.Rows(1).Delete
            r = r - 2
        End If
        If offSet > 10 Then
            Sheet1.Rows(offSet - 8).Delete
            Sheet1.Rows(offSet - 8).Delete
            Sheet1.Rows(offSet - 8).Delete
            r = r - 3
        End If
        .document.parentWindow.execScript "submitHTMLTableNavigator(" + CStr(offSet) + ");"
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
    Wend
    'Sheet1.Range("A:F").WrapText = False
    IE.Quit
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Looking forward for someone to help me here.
Thanking you in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: What did you try, and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your reply. I tried to filter the data for the desired date on the website first and then did the crawling, but it reads all the records on the website. I am not understanding where do I set the "currentDate" filter in the code to fetch only today's records. I request you to please help me here. Thank you.

Comment: Nobody to help me with the code correction...??? ;-(

Comment: There are two input named "dateFrom" and "DateTo" on that page: have you tried placing some date values in those inputs?

Comment: Thank you very much for replying back Tim. I did try setting the "dateFrom" and "dateTo" on the webpage and then passing the url to the VBA code. It does not work in either case. I even tried writing an AutoFilter code to the Date column in the excel sheet which looks like this:                                                               If UserForm1.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
   Sheet1.Range("D").AutoFilter Field:=4,Criteria1:=">=14/10/2014", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=15/10/2014"
End If

Comment: This AutoFilter code does not work either. It filters out everything. Will you please help me correcting this AutoFilter code? I did go through the other posts on SOF for the same, but not able to figure out what's wrong. Need you help badly.. Thank you Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This filter worked for me:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter _
           Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=10/13/2014", Operator:=xlAnd, _
           Criteria2:="<=10/14/2014"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim for the solution. I worked it out and its running just the way I want it to work! Thank you once again.. :-) have a nice day